# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) - but I am including two variables in my unpacking?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to unpack a list of items, but I am  accessing it from my terminal and I haven't come across the syntax before:

```
>>>print(files)
[('/tmp/xetra_lv3-eobi-2022-08-11-lk1dv85l/1401_00_D_08_A_20220617.rar', ------------------------------
    id: 21266441
    data_file_group_id: 157
    dl_date: 2022-06-17
    file_path: /raw/xetra_lv3/eobi/2022/06/17/1401_00_D_08_A_20220617.rar
    status: S3UPLOAD_SUCCEEDED
            ), ('/tmp/xetra_lv3-eobi-2022-08-11-lk1dv85l/1401_00_D_08_A_20220617.rar_0', ------------------------------
    id: 21266455
    data_file_group_id: 157
    dl_date: 2022-06-17
    file_path: /raw/xetra_lv3/eobi/2022/06/17/1401_00_D_08_A_20220617.rar_0
    status: S3UPLOAD_SUCCEEDED
            ), ('/tmp/xetra_lv3-eobi-2022-08-11-lk1dv85l/1401_00_D_08_B_20220617.rar', ------------------------------
    id: 21266456
    data_file_group_id: 157
    dl_date: 2022-06-17
    file_path: /raw/xetra_lv3/eobi/2022/06/17/1401_00_D_08_B_20220617.rar
    status: S3UPLOAD_SUCCEEDED
            ), ('/tmp/xetra_lv3-eobi-2022-08-11-lk1dv85l/1401_00_D_08_B_20220617.rar_0', ------------------------------
    id: 21266440
    data_file_group_id: 157
    dl_date: 2022-06-17
    file_path: /raw/xetra_lv3/eobi/2022/06/17/1401_00_D_08_B_20220617.rar_0
    status: S3UPLOAD_SUCCEEDED
            )]
```

I am trying to unpack `files` by doing:

```
data_list = [fname for fname, rdf in files]
```

But when I run the above, I get the error:

```
>   data_list = [fname for fname, rdf in files]
[2022-08-11T11:25:51.549Z] E   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Following discussions in the comment, here is some additional information. So I previously had this function:

```
def pass1_statuses(files, update_status=None, started=False, persist: bool = True):
     
    file_list = []

    for fname, rdf in files:
        if rdf.status in (RawDataFileStatus.download_started, RawDataFileStatus.download_succeeded,
                          RawDataFileStatus.download_failed, RawDataFileStatus.s3_upload_started,
                          RawDataFileStatus.s3_upload_failed):
            LOGGER.warning('A record of {} exists, but it has not yet been placed in storage '
                           'successfully. Current status: {}'.format(fname, rdf.status))
        elif (rdf.status in (RawDataFileStatus.pass1_started, RawDataFileStatus.pass1_succeeded)
                and not started):
            LOGGER.debug('The file ({}) current status is {}. It may have already been '
                         'processed.'.format(fname, rdf.status))
        file_list.append(fname)

    if update_status and persist:
        with session_scope_retries() as session:
            for fname, rdf in files:
                # Retrieve the actual raw data file from the proxy
                raw_data_file = get_raw_data_file(session, recid=rdf.id)
                log_raw_data_event(session, update_status, raw_data_file)

    return file_list
```

And there was NO error when this is run- and this is the equivalent of my list comprehension above??

Comment: You’re trying to get `fname, rdf` from a list of tuples, but the `in files` part of your comprehension would return one item per iteration, so you expect 2 values but what you’re calling only returns 1.

Comment: @wkl Yes, and this one item is a tuple and it's unpacked in `fname` and `rdf`. Something like `print([i for i,j in [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]])` runs without problems.

Comment: You could use a loop with `for entry in files:` and in the body `print(len(entry), entry)`. Then find the entry with more then 2 elements (or add an `if` statement to only print the entries with more than 2 elements).

Comment: @Matthias How do you know it's a tuple?

Comment: @KellyBundy That's a good point. I just looked at the representation, but this could be the representation of a different object than a tuple. A `print(type(files[0]))` should give the answer.

Comment: @Matthias could you suggest a solution please- I don't quite follow! Apologies

Comment: @Matthias Yeah... If it **is** a tuple, then it looks like it does have two elements (since there's one comma), so wouldn't produce that error...

Comment: @KellyBundy that is what I thought too! That's why I am saying it is so strange

Comment: So what do you see when you print the type as suggested?

Comment: Actually, also `print(type(files))` to be sure that's indeed a list...

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: I really don't understand why this isn't working, based on everything I know about lists and list comprehension, plus what I added at the end of my question I don't believe it should be returning a ValueError!

Comment: What's the type on the second element in your tuples e.g. `print(type(files[0][1]))`? Not because I suspect it's causing the problem, but in order to try to reproduce with something as close to yours as possible.

Comment: Ahh this is a hard one, because it is a complicated file, I don't believe it will have much meaning -> `<class 'dbutils.models.service.RawDataFile'>`

Comment: We're the list comprehension and the print done on the same (list?) object? Or did you run your code, it crashed, you restarted the code in the debugger, and then possibly printed a different one?

Comment: Ahh okay, I see now- perhaps this is the case. I am running it in the debugger and there could be multiple instances of 'files' being passed in. I am running it now to see if this is indeed the case

Comment: Kelly, can you read the bottom of my question please I have added more details. As this leads me to believe that this is not the issue

Comment: I did read that already, doesn't tell me much.

Comment: That previous code does look equivalent in the relevant regard, yes. Maybe the previous `files` data was not equivalent, i.e., previously you only had 2-tuples and now you don't?

Comment: Hmm I am running the same code against it, so iuts very stange